# How to make exception in `convert_objects` in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Here's my `dtypes` of my dataset, `df.dtypes`

```
customer_id                              int64
device_id                                object
...
email                                    object
email_counts                             object
...
white_collar_count                       object
dtype: object
```

I am converting all to numerics with
`df = df.convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)`
and then `df.dtypes` is

```
customer_id                              int64
device_id                                float64
...
email                                    float64
email_counts                             float64
...
white_collar_count                       float64
dtype: object
```

I want to make exception on `e-mail` and `device_id` so the `df.dtypes` is

```
customer_id                              int64
device_id                                object
...
email                                    object
email_counts                             float64
...
white_collar_count                       float64
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`difference`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.difference.html) for filter out columns in list:

```
feature_exist = pd.DataFrame({'A':list('abcdef'),
                   'B':[4,5,4,5,5,4],
                   'C':[7,8,9,4,2,3],
                   'D':[1,3,5,7,1,0],
                   'email':[5,3,6,9,2,4],
                   'F':list('aaabbb')}).astype(str)

print (feature_exist)
   A  B  C  D email  F
0  a  4  7  1     5  a
1  b  5  8  3     3  a
2  c  4  9  5     6  a
3  d  5  4  7     9  b
4  e  5  2  1     2  b
5  f  4  3  0     4  b

cols = feature_exist.columns.difference(['email'])
feature_exist[cols] = feature_exist[cols].convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)

print (feature_exist.dtypes)
A        object
B         int64
C         int64
D         int64
email    object
F        object
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

Try -

```
exceptional_cols = ['email']
feature_exist = pd.concat([feature_exist.drop(email, axis=1).convert_objects(convert_numeric=True), feature_exist[exceptional_cols]], , axis=1, sort=False)
```

**Explanation**

Drop the `cols` you don't want to convert and convert the remaining ones -

```
feature_exist.drop(email, axis=1).convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)
```

Once done, append back the column that you dropped by using `concat`.

This will help you separate the columns that you don't want to convert.